# Display body margins

Tags: margins, paper-size, layout

Taking as reference the image given here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/page_size_and_margins, I'm trying to display the body margins, that is, the margin corresponding to the region delimited by (7) and (8) on the link.

So far, closest result I could get is obtained by using:

```
\noindent \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.98\textheight][t]{0.985\textwidth}
\begin{titlepage}
....
\end{titlepage}
\end{minipage}}
```

I'm also using `\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2cm, left=3 cm, right=2 cm, includefoot]{geometry}` in the preamble. I'm assuming these values relate to these body margins I mentioned, but I'm not fully sure...

Is there a better way?

Comment: Does `\usepackage[showframe, margin=20mm]]{geometry}` (observe `showframe`) gives what you after?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. It gives additional margins and also applies to all pages whereas I want it just for one page. But I guess that solution I found will work well enough as a quick fix, maybe I should just forget about it.

Comment: @Ashitaka The question is not very clear. The Image in the page you linked is created [by the package `layout`](https://ctan.org/pkg/layout) through the command `\layout`. But I'm guessing this isn't what you want either? As I understand it you want to add a frame to the document body? If That is true your question might be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449290/